# Pass additional Extras with RecognizerIntent

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, recognizer-intent

I am trying to call the RecognizerIntent from my app, and get the results back associated with a specific ID.  I am struggling to figure out how I can pass my id so that it is returned in the extras of the results.

Initially, I tried something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
intent.putExtra(TasksDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID,taskId);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
```

Unfortunately, extras put on this intent are not included in bundle passed to onActivityResult

Looking through the documentation, there is a field, EXTRA_RESULTS_PENDINGINTENT_BUNDLE which appears to let you do what I want.  But I have been unable to figure out how to properly implement it.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
Intent pending = new Intent(v.getContext(),Main.class);
pending.putExtra(TasksDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, itId);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(v.getContext(),RESULT_SPEECH,pending,0);

Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS_PENDINGINTENT,pIntent);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS_PENDINGINTENT_BUNDLE,pending.getExtras());
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
```

Unfortunately, this does not work.  Currently, OnActivityResult always receives a resultCode of 0, instead of -1 (ie. RESULT_OK)

Can anyone point me in the direction of an example or help me understand what I need to do here to achieve the goal of setting an id and receiving it back with the results of the speech to text?